# What is this anime that has a strange flying sun totem?

Tags: night-warriors

I don't think the one I watched is a full episode or something. It should be a trailer, and I assume it is an anime because I watched it on a VCD of a magazine about manga/anime.

I watched it during 2000-2003 if I didn't remember it wrong. But it doesn't necessarily mean that the show is a 2000-2003 production. The magazine should be older than the month I watched it.

The background of the anime seemed pretty dark. I remember a flying sun totem (not sure if it flew by itself or was the face of something else) appearing in different places and in each place there are characters fighting. And the character on the sun totem's side (I assume) always won and killed the other -- an invasion maybe.

The flying sun totem looks a bit like this pic: abstract flare around the circle, and a face (but filled up the circle part in that anime).

[image: sun totem]

Sorry for giving unclear information about the anime. The only thing that still impresses me is the strange flying sun totem.

---

**Update:**

The totem was in yellow or similar colors, and was larger than the characters.

Comment: did the sun look like, uh... [this](http://moe.animecharactersdatabase.com/uploads/chars/4758-318531708.jpg)? it's from [Rave](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/groove-adventure-rave)...

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I don't think so... it should be yellow. And the plot should be darker. Were many people killed in Groove Adventure Rave?

Comment: I don't really know the anime but some people die in manga

Comment: Do you remember the magazine's name?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko it was a magazine in China. Can't remember the name. Actually I only got the VCD at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Night Warriors: Darkstalkers' Revenge](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1952/Vampire_Hunter) (1997–1998)

> The world is a dark, brooding place populated by humans, but ruled in reality by powerful beings known as the Darkstalkers, and there is constant conflict between them as they try to determine who is the most powerful of them all. Zombies, vampires, werewolves - all of them compete in contests of strength and sheer will to attain their own personal goals.
>
> All of this becomes moot when a race of Aztec robots called the Huitzil decide that humanity isn't worth saving, and start waging war on the world, while in the sky, a solar god from outer space plots the conquest of Earth. And the Darkstalkers must become unwilling allies in order to save the world.

The sun totem spits out Pyron, the boss of the series, who challenges every monster character and wins all battles until his defeat in the end. The background of the anime is pretty dark most of the time, as you can see in this screenshot of the sun totem:

[image: The sun totem]